# paintComponent(g) Not Scaling BufferedImage?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, scaling

In my main class for my Game, I have the following code:

```
// dimensions
public static final int WIDTH = 266;
public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
public static final int SCALE = 3;

// game loop
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = true;
public static int count = 0;

// rendering
private BufferedImage image;

public Panel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

}

public void run() {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final double numUpdates = 30.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / numUpdates;
    double delta = 0;

    while(running) {

        long current = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (current - start) / ns;
        start = current;
        if(delta >= 1) {
            update();
            delta--;
        }
        repaint();

    }

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(new Color(230, 100, 100));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rage Mage");

    frame.add(new Panel());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

The `image` isn't being scaled though, it's drawn at it's actual dimensions, rather than having it's dimensions multiplied by 3 (`SCALE`).

Also, if I remove the `super.paintComponent(g);` line and the `g.drawImage(...);` line, the rectangle is still being rendered.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `drawImage()` scales the image? The very first line of the Javadoc of the method you are invoking states: "Draws as much of the specified image **as has already been scaled** to fit inside the specified rectangle.". You would need to do the actual scaling beforehand, by, for example, using the `getScaledInstance` method of the image.

Comment: @Ordous i read it right now, and yes, thats the solution!! - but don't use Image.getScaledInstance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to fit the entire Jpanel, you should use the following:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(new Color(230, 100, 100));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

}
```

This will make your image to be scaled to the whole Jpanel. Of course, you will not see the rectangle because the image will be drawn over it.

Also, be sure to actually put something in your image.

Answer (score 2):

use the scaling method to draw a scaled instance of your image:

```
Graphics gr; 
gr.drawImage(0,0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,null);
```

as seen on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29

@MadProgrammer gave me also some interesting hint: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html - have a look at this!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint on `getScaledInstance`, I've had some problems with it, but not enough to do any actual research into alternatives.

Comment: don't say thanks to me - the thanks goes to MadProgrammer, he wrote about that...